# how to loop through django queryset data and set the values in an array not a dictionnary

Tags: python, django

I Have to loop through data of the query set in django and put the data into an array without specifying the model name.

My Django view:

```
 permissions = Permission.objects.all().order_by('perm_label')
 arrayData = []
 for type in permissions:
      for value in type:
         arrayData.append(value)
```

This is giving me error:

```
Permission' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is `for value in type` doing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "without specifying the model name" ? In your code you specified the model as `Permission`.

Comment: It also does not make much sense to use a list over a dictionary: the order of the columns is unknown, so that means that this can generate the same data in a "random" order.

Comment: @Ralf: I think the OP makes abstraction of this.

Comment: @Ralf I don't want to make arraydata.append(type.perm_label) i don't want to specify the column name i wan't to loop through data

Comment: @Ralf i mean by model name the column in the database

Comment: You can use the method [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get a `dict` for each object; like `Permission.objects.values().order_by(...)` . Is that what you need?

Comment: @Ralf okay this is it but how to append it in an array and not an array of dictionary for example ["name",0,0,3] and loop through the rows and append each row to the array

Comment: @Boutros I added an answer with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try this:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
>>> field_name_list = []

>>> qs = Permission.objects.all()
>>> qs = qs.filter(content_type__id=1)    # I added this line to make this sample output shorter
>>> qs = qs.values(*field_name_list)

>>> final_data = []
>>> for elem in qs:
...     print(type(elem))
...     print(elem)
...     for v in elem.values():
...         final_data.append(v)
<class 'dict'>
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Can add log entry', 'content_type_id': 1, 'codename': 'add_logentry'}
<class 'dict'>
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Can change log entry', 'content_type_id': 1, 'codename': 'change_logentry'}
<class 'dict'>
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Can delete log entry', 'content_type_id': 1, 'codename': 'delete_logentry'}

>>> final_data
[1, 'Can add log entry', 1, 'add_logentry', 2, 'Can change log entry', 1, 'change_logentry', 3, 'Can delete log entry', 1, 'delete_logentry']
```

This uses the method [`queryset.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) to have each `Permission` instance be represented by a `dict` instead of an actual model instance.

If you leave `field_name_list` as an empty list, then you will get all fields for that model, but you can also add the names of the fields you want.

Then, you can use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to just get the values (the column values for that row) without the keys (which would be the column names).

Comment: it is returning only the first element of the data

Comment: What do you mean? Only the first row from the database table or only the first field value of each row?

Comment: it worked but it is returning only the first row in the database and not all the rows that i need to display them do you know why? i am putting qs.values() without any data does this affect it???

Comment: No, `QuerySet.values()` does not affect the amount of rows that are retrieved, it only affects the columns. Are you sure there is no call to `.filter()`, or maybe you are exiting the loop after the first element?

Comment: My final question is : how to remove for example the first element in the dictionary and it's value and only appear the other values

Comment: There is no "first" element in a dict, they are unordered. You will have to specify the keys you want using `field_name_list` from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

we can use the `values()` for that

```
arrayData = []
user = User.objects.all().values()

for data in user:
    arrayData.append(data["field_name"])
```